# Create buffer around one category of polylines in feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, features

I have a feature that contains polylines of fluvial and tidal streams in ArcMap.

I want to create a buffer around the tidal streams only. I tried selecting only the tidal streams using the attribute table and then using the buffer tool in the editor toolbar, but got a notification saying it's not possible to buffer a network of features.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: You need to use [Buffer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) tool from ArcToolbox not from editor toolbar.

Comment: When I try using the buffer tool from ArcToolbox I can't figure out how to select only one category of streams from the feature?

Comment: If the attribute table has information about the category you want, then use select by attribute to select those features, and then apply buffer on the selected feature from ArcToolbox.

Comment: Thanks, I used select by attribute to create a new layer and then ran the buffering tool.

Comment: I converted my comments to an answer to help others having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the attribute table has information about the category of the stream that you want, then use the following steps:

1. [Select by attributes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-attributes.htm) to select those features, and then
2. Apply [Buffer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) tool on the selected feature from ArcToolbox.